# Detect errors and unexpected values while applying functions to columns in a PySpark DataFrame, capturing comments in a separate column for each row

Tags: python, pyspark, data-science, bigdata, data-manipulation

I have one pyspark dataframe by the name df. The df have 170 columns. The column name of df represent the function name and we have to applied that function on that column.

For example the df contains fields like square, cube, rename.... then we have to apply those function(square(), cube(), rename()....) on the respective column. I have created different functions according to their name and their task. If any error or any unexpected values come in function while calling then we append comment like  "-ve value in square function." or "-ve value in cube function." or "null value in rename function." in a python list.

So initialize one column in df by the name 'comments' with null value.
Now my task is to start applying function acc. to their name. After applying all the function the comment list either filled with comments or it will be empty. Now dump this comment list into comment field according to their row number.

**For example,**

In row number 1 of df, we have data like,

square | cube | rename

'a'| 'b' | 'hi'

then after applying all functions the comment list = [wrong value in square function, wrong value in cube function].
Dump this comment list in row no. 1 of comments field of df.

In row number 2 of df, we have data like,

square | cube | rename

'h'| -1 | 'hi'

then after applying all functions the comment list = [wrong value in square function].
Dump this comment list in row no. 2 of comments field of df.

The example of function and list i have made are,

comments = []

def square_func(value):
try:
return value ** 2
except Exception:
comments.append("wrong value in square function.")
return value

I have tried applying function column wise but there is no hope to go with this approach. And going in row wise is not possible as the volume of the data is big.

Comment: the question is too long. [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: what have you tried so far ?
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)